# Alternate to parse_ini_file php

Tags: php

What is the alternate to parse the config file to give the absolute path in php.

ie) I am reading the db config file like:

```
 $config     = parse_ini_file('../../../config.ini');
```

I need to give the absolute path for the above like:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/<my_path>/config.ini';
```

I need to avoid the use of '../../' in my paths

If i use:

> $config     = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].' /my_path/my_path/config.ini';

I get

> Illegal string offset 'username'

Comment: And isn't that working? You didn't actually state what's not working with using absolute path

Comment: Doesn't this `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` help fix your problem?

Comment: you can create a definitions file and in there declare a global shorthand `define('BASE_PATH', '/path/to/www/root');`

Comment: have updated the question

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs +1

Comment: How is this error possible? `Illegal string offset 'username'`?

Answer (score 1):

In your Root folder of the project maintain a `config.php` there you can add such data. This is what followed by many PHP projects including WordPress.

For example from WordPress

```
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

They defined `ABSPATH` in `wp-config.php` and it holds **absolute path** of application. So you refer them in your application wherever you want,

In your case this could be like following.

```
parse_ini_file(ABSPATH. 'config.ini');
```

Comment: i had actually kept the config.php in my root folder, felt like i need to keep it in project specific folder

Comment: Wha do you mean by project specific folder?

Comment: meaning my main file and config file are in seperate locations, want to keep my config.php in a seperate folder though

Comment: ok achieved using getcwd(), i moved the config.php in the same folder

Comment: `config.ini` is inside of your project folder? or outside of it?
If it is inside you no need to use `getcwd()` because you have your project path already in config.php if you have mentioned constant like `ABSPATH` which is good practise

Comment: I placed the config.php inside the same project folder

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it using below:

```
$path = getcwd().'/mypath/config.ini'; 
$config  = parse_ini_file($path);
```